# Use Bahnschrift font with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, bold, italic

I'm looking to write a document with Bahnschrift, Microsoft's implementation of DIN 1451 font standard. So I made the code to see if I can have bold and italic font.

```latex
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Bahnschrift.ttf}

\begin{document}
Bahnschrift

\textit{Bahnschrift}

\textbf{Bahnschrift}

\textbf{\textit{Bahnschrift}}

\end{document}
```

But I got this :

[image: Output]

Is there a way to display bold and italic Bahnschrift with LaTeX ? If not, which similar font would work ?

Comment: Maybe not yet: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355104/tex-luatex-xetex-fontspec-support-for-opentype-variable-fonts

Comment: @DavidPurton Therefore, which similar font would work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for a free version of DIN 1451 and found [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/7179/76771) Stackexchange post mentioning **[DINish](https://github.com/playbeing/dinish/)**, with which the font weights work out of the box:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Dinish}

\begin{document}
    Bahnschrift
    
    \textit{Bahnschrift}
    
    \textbf{Bahnschrift}
    
    \textbf{\textit{Bahnschrift}}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could fake the variants (imho the font has not real italic/slanted anyway):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Bahnschrift}%
 [
  BoldFont={Bahnschrift},
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=1.6},  % {RawFeature={embolden=1.6}}  with lualatex
  ItalicFont={Bahnschrift},
  ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2},
  BoldItalicFont={Bahnschrift},
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2,FakeBold=1.6},
 ]

\begin{document}
blub {\bfseries blub \itshape blub} \itshape blub
\end{document}
```

[image]