# LuaLaTeX: Smarter font selection macro for super-families

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

> **NOTE: This question is not answered yet. The only "answer" to this question from user Davislor does not answer this question, even though it has up-votes to make it look like. Please feel free to answer if you have a real solution.**

Fontspec with LuaLaTeX works well for small font families, but appears cumbersome to use with super-families. A modern super-family can contain tens of fonts in Weight/Width/Slope (WWS) matrix. As an example Avenir Next has 32 fonts in one family.

Opentype font tables contain fields that can be used to accurately select a font in a super family: 1) WWS family name, 2) WWS subfamily name. So ideally, one should be able to set a family by specifying just family name, and optionally select a subfamily by just specifying subfamily name. Is there a LuaLaTeX way to do that?

> Note 1): This sub family name is not always a substring of font's "full name", so you cannot do string concatenation trick and use fontspec :)

> Note 2) If WWS fields are missing in the font, then the appropriate fields to resolve the font are: 1) font family name, and 2) font subfamily name. So somewhere a if-else statement will be needed.

```
\fontfamily{Avenir Next LT Pro}
.
.
.
Hello world {\fstyle{Ultra Light Italic} Hello world} Hello world
```

Here are some relevant screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should be able to set up a `.fontspec` file for the font, I think especially with the enhansed set of standard font weight names in recent releases.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's exactly something I want to avoid, when I mention it is cumbersome. The interface proposal I have should make things as simple as selecting a font style in a WYSIWYG application like macOS Pages. The point is there should be no need to do special setup/mapping to use fonts. I would rather use these macros instead of standard ``\bfseries``, ``\itshape``, etc

Comment: hmm luatex could presumably pick up the named weights from the font and allow \fontfamily{Avenir Next}\fontseries{Bold Condensed}\selectfont` but I don't think it does currently. It probably wouldn't be too hard actually although do you know any free font example with that many variants to test on....

Comment: There are basically two issues: 1. WWS names are terrible when it comes to optical sizes. When a font has different optical sizes, they get classified as different families which makes them a pain to use. 2. Integrating this into NFSS (which is particularly important for such big families since it natively supports the idea of such font matrices) requires to interpret subfamily names which only leads to issues since many fonts mess with these names for "compatibility" with their designers favorite programs.

Comment: IMO the `STAT` table is much more promising, but I don't have any good example families using it to play with in order to implement something there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found OpenSans and Inter: https://github.com/googlefonts/opensans, https://github.com/rsms/inter. Open sans has all 3 WWS under same family, inter does not have width but more elaborate weights.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger in comment above

Comment: @MarcelKrüger 1) For optical sizes, I don't see the problem. Given the optical sizes are different families, they can get resolved with different ``\fontfamily``. For instance, Minion 3 has these font families: Minion 3, Minion 3 Caption, Minion 3 Subhead, Minion 3 Display. Each has the usual Regular, Italic, ... which will get resolved using ``\fstyle``. 2) I don't care integrating the macro into any existing functionality including mapping them to ``\bfseries``. ``\itshape`` etc, so not sure why I would care about NFSS?

Answer (score 8):

You would do this with an extensive list of `FontFace=` options, ideally in a `.fontspec` or `.sty` file.  I don’t have that specific font to test, so I downloaded [this version of Noto Serif](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/noto-serif) into a subdirectory named `fonts`.  Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSerif]{
  Path=fonts/,
  Extension=.ttf,
  FontFace={ul}{n}{Font={*-Thin}},
  FontFace={ul}{it}{Font={*-ThinItalic}},
  FontFace={el}{n}{Font={*-ExtraLight}},
  FontFace={el}{it}{Font={*-ExtraLightItalic}},
  FontFace={l}{n}{Font={*-Light}},
  FontFace={l}{it}{Font={*-LightItalic}},
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  FontFace={mb}{n}{Font={*-Medium}},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{Font={*-MediumItalic}},
  FontFace={sb}{n}{Font={*-SemiBold}},
  FontFace={sb}{it}{Font={*-SemiBoldItalic}},
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  FontFace={eb}{n}{Font={*-ExtraBold}},
  FontFace={eb}{it}{Font={*-ExtraBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={ub}{n}{Font={*-Black}},
  FontFace={ub}{it}{Font={*-BlackItalic}},
  FontFace={uluc}{n}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedThin}},
  FontFace={uluc}{it}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedThinItalic}},
  FontFace={eluc}{n}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedExtraLight}},
  FontFace={eluc}{it}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedExtraLightItalic}},
  FontFace={luc}{n}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedLight}},
  FontFace={luc}{it}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedLightItalic}},
  FontFace={uc}{n}{Font={*-ExtraCondensed}},
  FontFace={uc}{it}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedItalic}},
  FontFace={mbuc}{n}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedMedium}},
  FontFace={mbuc}{it}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedMediumItalic}},
  FontFace={sbuc}{n}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedSemiBold}},
  FontFace={sbuc}{it}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedSemiBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={buc}{n}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedBold}},
  FontFace={buc}{it}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={ebuc}{n}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedExtraBold}},
  FontFace={ebuc}{it}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedExtraBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={ubuc}{n}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedBlack}},
  FontFace={ubuc}{it}{Font={*-ExtraCondensedBlackItalic}},
  FontFace={ulec}{n}{Font={*-CondensedThin}},
  FontFace={ulec}{it}{Font={*-CondensedThinItalic}},
  FontFace={elec}{n}{Font={*-CondensedExtraLight}},
  FontFace={elec}{it}{Font={*-CondensedExtraLightItalic}},
  FontFace={lec}{n}{Font={*-CondensedLight}},
  FontFace={lec}{it}{Font={*-CondensedLightItalic}},
  FontFace={ec}{n}{Font={*-Condensed}},
  FontFace={ec}{it}{Font={*-CondensedItalic}},
  FontFace={mbec}{n}{Font={*-CondensedMedium}},
  FontFace={mbec}{it}{Font={*-CondensedMediumItalic}},
  FontFace={sbec}{n}{Font={*-CondensedSemiBold}},
  FontFace={sbec}{it}{Font={*-CondensedSemiBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={bec}{n}{Font={*-CondensedBold}},
  FontFace={bec}{it}{Font={*-CondensedBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={ebec}{n}{Font={*-CondensedExtraBold}},
  FontFace={ebec}{it}{Font={*-CondensedExtraBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={ubec}{n}{Font={*-CondensedBlack}},
  FontFace={ubec}{it}{Font={*-CondensedBlackItalic}},
  FontFace={ulc}{n}{Font={*-SemiCondensedThin}},
  FontFace={ulc}{it}{Font={*-SemiCondensedThinItalic}},
  FontFace={elc}{n}{Font={*-SemiCondensedExtraLight}},
  FontFace={elc}{it}{Font={*-SemiCondensedExtraLightItalic}},
  FontFace={lc}{n}{Font={*-SemiCondensedLight}},
  FontFace={lc}{it}{Font={*-SemiCondensedLightItalic}},
  FontFace={c}{n}{Font={*-SemiCondensed}},
  FontFace={c}{it}{Font={*-SemiCondensedItalic}},
  FontFace={mbc}{n}{Font={*-SemiCondensedMedium}},
  FontFace={mbc}{it}{Font={*-SemiCondensedMediumItalic}},
  FontFace={sbc}{n}{Font={*-SemiCondensedSemiBold}},
  FontFace={sbc}{it}{Font={*-SemiCondensedSemiBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={bc}{n}{Font={*-SemiCondensedBold}},
  FontFace={bc}{it}{Font={*-SemiCondensedBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={ebc}{n}{Font={*-SemiCondensedExtraBold}},
  FontFace={ebc}{it}{Font={*-SemiCondensedExtraBoldItalic}},
  FontFace={ubc}{n}{Font={*-SemiCondensedBlack}},
  FontFace={ubc}{it}{Font={*-SemiCondensedBlackItalic}}
}

\setmainfont{NotoSerif}

\makeatletter
\edef\current@weight{m}
\edef\current@extent{}

\DeclareRobustCommand\fontweight[1]{%
  \edef\current@weight{#1}%
  \update@series%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\fontextent[1]{%
  \edef\current@extent{#1}%
  \update@series%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\update@series{%
  \expandafter\ifx\current@extent\relax%
    \fontseries{\current@weight}%
  \else%
    \ifx\current@weight m%
      \fontseries{\current@extent}%
    \else%
      \fontseries{\current@weight\current@extent}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\ulweight{\fontweight{ul}\selectfont}
\newcommand\elweight{\fontweight{el}\selectfont}
\newcommand\ltweight{\fontweight{l}\selectfont}
\newcommand\mdweight{\fontweight{m}\selectfont}
\newcommand\mbweight{\fontweight{mb}\selectfont}
\newcommand\sbweight{\fontweight{sb}\selectfont}
\newcommand\bfweight{\fontweight{b}\selectfont}
\newcommand\ebweight{\fontweight{eb}\selectfont}
\newcommand\ubweight{\fontweight{ub}\selectfont}
\newcommand\ucwidth{\fontextent{uc}\selectfont}
\newcommand\ecwidth{\fontextent{ec}\selectfont}
\newcommand\cdwidth{\fontextent{c}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\mdweight Noto Serif \textit{Italic}
\ulweight Thin \textit{Italic}
\elweight ExtraLight \textit{Italic}
\ltweight Light \textit{Italic}
\mbweight Medium \textit{Italic}
\sbweight Semibold \textit{Italic}
\bfweight Bold \textit{Italic}
\ebweight Extra-Bold \textit{Italic}
\ubweight Heavy \textit{Italic}

\ucwidth
\mdweight Noto Serif Extra-Condensed \textit{Italic}
\ulweight Thin \textit{Italic}
\elweight ExtraLight \textit{Italic}
\ltweight Light \textit{Italic}
\mbweight Medium \textit{Italic}
\sbweight Semibold \textit{Italic}
\bfweight Bold \textit{Italic}
\ebweight Extra-Bold \textit{Italic}
\ubweight Heavy \textit{Italic}

\ecwidth
\mdweight Noto Serif Condensed \textit{Italic}
\ulweight Thin \textit{Italic}
\elweight ExtraLight \textit{Italic}
\ltweight Light \textit{Italic}
\mbweight Medium \textit{Italic}
\sbweight Semibold \textit{Italic}
\bfweight Bold \textit{Italic}
\ebweight Extra-Bold \textit{Italic}
\ubweight Heavy \textit{Italic}

\cdwidth
\mdweight Noto Serif Semi-Condensed \textit{Italic}
\ulweight Thin \textit{Italic}
\elweight ExtraLight \textit{Italic}
\ltweight Light \textit{Italic}
\mbweight Medium \textit{Italic}
\sbweight Semibold \textit{Italic}
\bfweight Bold \textit{Italic}
\ebweight Extra-Bold \textit{Italic}
\ubweight Heavy \textit{Italic}
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Serif Sample]

I re-invented the wheel there: the [`nfssext-cfr` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nfssext-cfr/nfssext-cfr.pdf) by @cfr also defines commands to set weight and width separately, and I used similar names.  If you also want commands corresponding to `\textit`, `\textup`, and so on, you would define them with `\DeclareTextFontCommand\textul{\ulwidth}`, etc.

You might instead want to redefine the standard `\bfseries`, `\mdseries` and so on, so that bold condensed would be `\bfseries\cdseries` instead of `\bfweight\cdwidth`.  This is how `fontaxes` and `fontspec` handle `\itshape\scshape` for italic small caps.  I avoided overriding the standard commands here, but that means they aren’t compatible with the new ones.

Like most packages, I used the official LaTeX series names from [The LaTeX Font Installation Guide](https://texdoc.org/serve/fontinstallationguide/0#appendix.A), but note that `fontspec` allows you to give your series and shapes arbitrary names.  There is no reason you couldn’t set up `\fontweight{Semibold}\fontextent{Condensed}\selectfont` to work, or `\fontseries{SemiboldCondensed}\selectfont`.  Just declare `FontFace{SemiboldCondensed}{n}` instead of `FontFace{sbc}{n}`.

To enable options such as support for optical sizes or variable fonts, add them inside the braces after `Font=`, such as `FontFace{ebc}{n}{ Font={*-ExtraBoldCondensed}, SizeFeatures={...} }`.  See [the `fontspec` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) for the features you need.

LuaTeX 1.13 and up now [supports variable fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355104/tex-luatex-xetex-fontspec-support-for-opentype-variable-fonts) as well.

If you just want to use the human-readable names in your code, you could attempt something like `\fontspec{Avenir Next LT Pro Medium Condensed}`.  Loading fonts by display name is deprecated, however.

Comment: it is better to stick to the official series names of latex, as a number of internal setups, e.g. for series fallbacks, relies on them.

Comment: This is exact kind of stuff I want to avoid. Sorry voting down for this. As I mention in bounty, and comments to the description, there should be no "setup" necessary for any new font installed on the system. And your ``\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSerif]{...`` breaks that.

Comment: @reportaman I respectfully, but strongly, disagree. For one thing, different font super-families use different naming schemes, such as Heavy or Black, Semibold or Demibold, etc. If you tried to implement the Noto example with no set-up, using other display names, it would break even on a system with the OpenType version of the font installed.

Comment: @reportaman Authors are much better off loading a package that does the necessary set-up for semanting markup to work.

Comment: @reportaman That said, I’m guessing you want a Lua hook or wrapper for `\font` that remembers the family name and adds the subfamily to load the font.

Comment: @reportaman Also, you don’t actually need `\defaultfontfeatures...` there. You could write `\setmainfont{NotoSerif}[UprightFont = *-Regular, ...]` and swap `AvenirNewLTPro` for `NotoSerif`. I always use `\defaultfontfeatues` for convenience.

Comment: @Davislor That too is not something I want, because it has this need to do these mappings: ``\setmainfont{NotoSerif}[UprightFont = *-Regular, ItalicFont = *-Italic ... ]``, which vary from font to font.

Comment: @reportaman Okay, but if you don’t do something like that, you have to change every font command in your document whenever you want to change your font.

Comment: @reportaman Anyway, it sounds like your preference is not mine. Hope you get an answer you like better.

Comment: @Davislor The intention of these macros is two pronged: 1) To reduce the overhead from the time of installing font to trying its various styles in a document. 2) To reduce effort for day-to-day ad-hoc/quick documents written in luatex where one doesn't care about creating a template/class for other documents. The thing is, the current interface totally disregards such use case, thus limiting the kind of interaction one can have with tons of super families available online. This overhead also makes latex not so useful for one-time-use documents.

Comment: @reportaman Okay. Another approach might be to patch `\setmainfont`, etc., so that it guesses the names of the other series the way it does the defaults. So, if you load `FooPro`, it would look for `FooPro-Heavy` or `FooPro-Black` for the `ub` series the way it currently looks for `FooPro-Regular`, `FooPro-Medium`, etc.

Comment: @Davislor That will become unmaintanable over time. Fonts like Univers use a 3-digit numbering scheme. Speciality fonts like Ray, has names like Ray One, Ray Two, etc. Same with decoration fonts, And I bet there are non-Latin languages what use even more exciting names. Moreover, text editor can autocomplete these font styles. LaTeX team should realize that things they try to optimize do not matter at times (and actually become a weakness); for instance modern text editors can be extended to complete font style names so there is nothing to worry about it being verbose.