# Page footer with unicode characters not shown using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, unicode

I'm using `fancyhdr` at overleaf, but the page footer is not shown:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}       
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{LATEX Image/}}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\subsectionfont{\color{teal}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{teal}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\lfoot{राष्ट्रीयइलेक्ट्रॉनिकीएवंसूचनाप्रौद्योगिकीसंस्थान } 

\newlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}
\setlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}{1cm}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\Page@FrameHeight}
\newlength{\Page@FrameWidth}
\AddToShipoutPicture{
  \thinlines
  \setlength{\Page@FrameHeight}{\paperheight-\PageFrameTopMargin-\PageFrameBottomMargin}
  \setlength{\Page@FrameWidth}{\paperwidth-\PageFrameLeftMargin-\PageFrameRightMargin}
\put(\strip@pt\PageFrameLeftMargin,\strip@pt\PageFrameTopMargin){
    \framebox(\strip@pt\Page@FrameWidth, \strip@pt\Page@FrameHeight){}}}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do not take screenshots of code, but paste the code as text in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Do you use a Unicode engine (LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX)? If not, set the contents of `\lfoot` only after `\begin{document}` if it contains actual text and not only marks/macros etc. Also your code has a typo: `\userpackage{fancyhdr}` instead of `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` (you're most likely ignoring errors! Never ignore errors in LaTeX, all your output can be faulty if you ignore a single error! In Overleaf you'll have a small red rectangle with the number of errors above your PDF that indicates errors)

Comment: (i)I have fixed \usepackage{fancyhdr} spelling mistake, still footer not showing.

Comment: Your code is still not a minimal working example (see the link above) but a preamble only. So we still do not really know, what you are doing. However, it seems you are using `\pagestyle{plain}`, but `\lfoot` does only change page style `fancy`. So either use `\pagestyle{fancy}` or use `\fancypagestyle{plain}{…}` to also redefine page style `plain` as shown in the `fancyhdr` manual. Additionally you have to load a font (and ideally setup the language) for `राष्ट्रीयइलेक्ट्रॉनिकीएवंसूचनाप्रौद्योगिकीसंस्थान`. See the `Missing character` messages in the log.

Comment: you need to setup a font that supports your font, and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` will not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you use xelatex or lualatex as compiler, you can use fontspec package to use suitable Open Type font(s). For example, Shobhika font has both roman and deva letters.

[image: footer]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}       

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Shobhika}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lfoot{lfoot राष्ट्रीयइलेक्ट्रॉनिकीएवंसूचनाप्रौद्योगिकीसंस्थान }

\section{Text}
Text
\newpage
Text

\end{document}
```

---

If you use old versions to compile, you may have to explicitly set the font renderer to get the correct ligatures etc.

[image: foot2]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}       

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontscript{Devanagari}{dev2,deva}
\setmainfont{Shobhika}
\newfontfamily\fdeva[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Shobhika}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lfoot{lfoot fdeva \fdeva राष्ट्रीयइलेक्ट्रॉनिकीएवंसूचनाप्रौद्योगिकीसंस्थान }

{\fdeva राष्ट्रीयइलेक्ट्रॉनिकीएवंसूचनाप्रौद्योगिकीसंस्थान. }

National Institute of Electronics \& Information Technology

\section{Text}
Text
\newpage
Text

\end{document}
```

Also see [How to use Devanagari variable font in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630516/how-to-use-devanagari-variable-font-in-latex)

Comment: I tried both the tags you wrote, still getting error.

Comment: "still getting error" is too vague. Add detail to the question, show the error (from the log??) and the code that produced the error. I get no error.