# Recursive Font, multiple axes, fontspec, texlive 2022

Tags: fontspec, luahbtex

I've installed texlive 2022 pretest and play around with it.

I've found a font called Recursive, see here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Recursive#about and the website here: https://www.recursive.design/ . According to the manual here https://www.recursive.design/assets/arrowtype-recursive-sansmono-specimen.pdf there are multiple axes.

I've found this explanation how to use axes of font features, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591485/4736 .

But I fail to get italic axis working.

The above mentioned font comes with a variable font file, called Recursive-VariableFont_CASL,CRSV,MONO,slnt,wght.ttf, which I renamed to Recursive-VariableFont.ttf.

I fail to find any documentation about `+axis=`. Where is this documented? I'm using fontspec v2.8a.

What I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{%
   RawFeature={+axis={CRSV}}%, slnt, CASL, wght}},
   % RawFeature={+axis={wght=100}},
   % RawFeature={+axis={mono=0}},
   % RawFeature={+axis={slnt=0}},
   % RawFeature={+axis={CASL=0}},
}
\setmainfont[
   ItalicFont=Recursive-VariableFont.ttf,
   BoldFont=Recursive-VariableFont.ttf,
   BoldItalicFont=Recursive-VariableFont.ttf,
    BoldFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=500}}},
    BoldItalicFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=900}}},
    ItalicFeatures = {RawFeature={+axis={CRSV=1}}}
    ]{Recursive-VariableFont.ttf}

    \setmonofont{Recursive-VariableFont.ttf}[%
    RawFeature={+axis={mono=1}}]


    
\begin{document}
\par the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\par\textit{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\par\textbf{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\par\textbf{\textit{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}}

\texttt{Es irrt der Mensch..}

\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

The output:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `variable-recursive' with ``lualatex --jobname=variable-recursive  -file-line-error   --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode variable-recursive.tex''
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./variable-recursive.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)))
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(./variable-recursive.aux)
(/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1{/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./variable-recursive.aux))
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:49,3:12,4:1,5:96,6:10,7:460,9:34
</home/AW/.fonts/r/Recursive-VariableFont.ttf></home/AW/.fonts/r/Recursive-VariableFont.ttf></home/AW/.fonts/r/Recursive-VariableFont.ttf></home/AW/.fonts/r/R
ecursive-VariableFont.ttf></home/AW/.fonts/r/Recursive-VariableFont.ttf>
Output written on variable-recursive.pdf (1 page, 41296 bytes).
SyncTeX written on variable-recursive.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on variable-recursive.log.

TeX Output finished at Tue Mar  1 18:03:24
```

But no italic letters in the pdf:

[image: no italic letters]

Any ideas?

Comment: Where the file `Recursive-VariableFont.ttf` can be found? I tried Get Recursive button at https://www.recursive.design/ but the downloaded zip file includes only fixed instances of the font.

Comment: @wipet Version with possible error might be from Google, see address in my post.

Comment: Address in your post is https://www.recursive.design/ , the blue button Get recursive is here, the Download is possible after the button is used. The file `ArrowType-Recursive-1.078.zip` is downloaded but there are only fixed instances of the font, no `Recursive-VariableFont.ttf`.

Comment: @wipet Look again...

Comment: I did look again but no file Recursive-VariableFont.ttf. Please, help me more. I described exactly what I did do without success. Please, be similar exact.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/arrowtype/recursive/blob/main/fonts/recursive_for_googlefonts/Recursive%5BCASL%2CCRSV%2CMONO%2Cslnt%2Cwght%5D.ttf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `axis` feature is documented in the `luaotfload` manual. Mostly this was already present in TeX Live 2021, but there it only worked with the `node` shaper and not the HarfBuzz based `harf` shaper. In TeX Live 2022 we extended it to also work with HarfBuzz. As you noticed the `node` implementation doesn't like uppercase axis names, but you can work around that in TL 2022 by switching to HarfBuzz:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
   Renderer=HarfBuzz,
   ItalicFont=Recursive-VariableFont.ttf,
   BoldFont=Recursive-VariableFont.ttf,
   BoldItalicFont=Recursive-VariableFont.ttf,
    BoldFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=500}}},
    BoldItalicFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=900}}},
    ItalicFeatures = {RawFeature={+axis={CRSV=1}}}
    ]{Recursive-VariableFont.ttf}

    \setmonofont{Recursive-VariableFont.ttf}[%
    Renderer=HarfBuzz,
    RawFeature={+axis={MONO=1}}]


    
\begin{document}
\par the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\par\textit{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\par\textbf{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\par\textbf{\textit{the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}}

\texttt{Es irrt der Mensch..}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Such fun! I'll try to knock something up with all these axes! Thank you!

Comment: @KeksDose I hid it a bit in the edit, but take care that the axis names (especially in harf mode) are case sensitive. E.g. you need `MONO`, not `mono`.

Comment: The bold italic doesn't work, as you can see if you compare the letter v, e.g. `BoldItalicFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=600},+axis={CRSV=1}}},` don't improve the output. Probably I've got to read the luaotfload manual.

Comment: You can only have a single `axis` feature, but it can set multiple values. So you would use e.g. `RawFeature={axis={wght=600,CRSV=1}}`.

Comment: Output is right, but I get a very strange error. `BoldItalicFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=600,CRSV=1}}},`, error: `</home/AW/.fonts/r/Recursive-VariableFont.ttf></home/AW/.fonts/r/Recursive-VariableFont.ttf...mf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-harf-define.lua:545: at
tempt to index a nil value (local 'extents').
<*> variable-recursive.tex
                       
...mf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-harf-define.lua:545: attempt to index a nil value (local 'extents').
<*> variable-recursive.tex`

Comment: Please add a bug report at https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues

Comment: See here: https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/215