# Is there anything I can do to make LuaLaTeX compile faster? (in 2022)

Tags: luatex, performance

I've been meaning to ask this question for a few years now - and I suppose it's time to ask it now, given the last similar question was asked (AFAIK) in 2017.

- I've tried precompiling formats as suggested in previous answers. But I can't seem to get it to work with `fontspec`.
- `luajitlatex` no longer seems to exist - allegedly, this is due to LuaJIT no longer being actively developed, though I seem to have been able to find a few forks (like this one: https://github.com/fperrad/LuaJIT) that are implementing features from Lua 5.3-5.4. I am not sure if it's possible to compile `luajittex` and `luajitlatex` with this forked library, however.
- All the other solutions seem to be out-of-date (as they are from almost 10 years ago) and I cannot seem to be able to replicate the answers on a modern TeX distribution (in 2022).

While I'm aware (paraphrasing a previous answer to this question) that it's indeed quite impressive to be able to compile a whole book in a matter of seconds with `lualatex` already, I'm still quite annoyed by the fact that `lualatex` takes at least 1-2 seconds to compile, regardless of document, when `pdflatex` can usually compile the same document in 0.1 seconds - when the only thing I want to do is use OpenType fonts and UTF-8.
(Surely, just these two features don't necessitate a 10-50x slowdown in compile time?)

Apologies if I went too much into a rant - I do know the TeX backend is an aging piece of software, but the lack of modern alternatives or any performance improvements (that I'm aware of) really saddens me.

Is the situation as bad as it seems, or are there other solutions to make `lualatex` compile faster, if the only things I want are OpenType fonts and UTF-8?

Comment: I'd kinda like to see an example of a document that under current lualatex takes 1-2 sec to compile and the same doc takes 0.1 under pdflatex.

Comment: The slow-down is predominantly due to loading of fonts. Can you post a short MWE with the fonts you are using? I have a document with lots of fonts and packages, it takes 13 seconds to load the preamble... Lots of software have this issue, word takes about 9 seconds on my comp and gimp about 27 seconds. GUI's give you the impression they load quickly, as you see movement... If you can post some code, I will give an example how to check for bottlenecks using timers

Comment: an opentype font may be 50 times larger than a tfm or pfa font, and the corresponding tables of hyphenation and ligatures etc are larger not to mention every character token is larger. You say "surely, just these two features don't necessitate a 10-50x slowdown in compile time?" but why do you expect it to be less? Note the run time is usually nothing like that factor slower, so on longer documents, or documents using slow macro code such as tikz, the differences are less, but a short document loading two or three big unicode fonts takes longer than a short document loading 8bit tex fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  There are East Asian Fonts with > 30,000 glyphs, so x50  is probably and underestimate

Comment: As far as I can see, the luatex version that will be shipped with texlive 2022 will be faster. I installed the pretest version and have been experimenting with some new lua features (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/635672/4736) and rendering seemed much faster.

Comment: @KeksDose Thank you so much for this suggestion (and for actually answering the question in the title). I installed the pretest and indeed things seem to be compiling much faster (haven't done any measurements yet, but I'm quite satisfied by how it's compiling now)

Comment: @daleif, my notes and drafts take about 0.5s with a precompiled LaTeX format, and over 2s with LuaLaTeX (TeX Live 2022). This is the reason I still use pdflatex, the update is fast enough to work as wysiwyg for me, lualatex is too slow.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a demonstration as to how to **slow** your document. The example first creates a small lua module `mytimer.lua`. To measure the time it takes for a particular section of the document you write `\timerstart{name}` and `\timerstop{name}`. Where you want to print the statistics you write `timer.statistics("document")`. This document takes about +20 seconds to print 10 pages. Experiment with it with your own fonts. The `LastResort` font can be downloaded from the unicode github page. It is not a very accurate test (as it does not measure the time the pdf takes to render on the screen). The code is capable to print almost all the the Unicode scripts through the main font and the fallback mechanism of the `luaotfloader`.

If you comment the call to `\fontspec` and do no printing other than the time it takes .3 seconds! So fonts and resource intensive packages like TikZ will slow down the compilation by orders of magnitude. I am also happy to report that TeX despite its age is a very fast program, the rumours that it slows down compilation due to its age are fake news. The same cannot be said for the undersigned!

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mytimer.lua}
-- table to hold time performance           
 M = M or {}
  local socket = require('socket')
  local time_stat = time_stat or {}
  local gettime = socket.gettime
   
-- start time measurement
time_stat["total"] = 0

-- @param done indicates timer was stopped
function start_time_measure(field)        
    time_stat[field] = {start = gettime(), done = false}
end

-- stop time measurement   
-- if two calls to stop will return wrong value
function stop_time_measure(field)         
    if not time_stat[field].done then 
       time_stat[field] = {total = gettime() - time_stat[field].start, done=true} 
    end   
end



 M.start = start_time_measure
 M.stop  = stop_time_measure 
 M.statistics = function(name) return time_stat[name].total end

-- M.start("document")
-- local s = 0
-- for i=1, 100000000 do s=s+1 end
-- M.stop("document")

-- print(M.statistics("document"))
-- print(M.statistics("document"))
return M
\end{filecontents*}

\directlua{timer = require("mytimer")}
\def\timerstart#1{\directlua{
timer.start("#1")}}
\def\timerstop#1{
\directlua{timer.stop("#1")}}

\def\timerprint#1{
\directlua{
timer.stop("#1")
tex.print("elapsed time (#1):", timer.statistics("#1"), "sec")
}}

\timerstart{document}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\edef\mycolor{404547}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
("myfallback",
{  
   "NotoSansPahawhHmong:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansNko:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansAdlam:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansMarchen:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansEthiopic:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansSoyombo:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansGrantha:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
   "NotoSansBassaVah:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansDeseret:mode=harf;", 
   "NotoSansOldHungarian:mode=harf;", 
   "NotoSansMeeteiMayek:mode=harf;",
   "NotoSansGurmukhi:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;", 
   "NotoSansOldTurkic:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansChakma:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansTelugu:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;", 
   "NotoSansSundanese:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;", 
   "NotoSansOsage:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;", 
   "NotoSansLao:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansCaucasianAlbanian:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansTaiViet:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSerifTangut:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansTifinagh:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansTagbanwa:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansTakri:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansOlChiki:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansLimbu:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansKhmer:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansCham:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansJavanese:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansSaurashtra:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansTamil:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansSamaritan:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansBengali:mode=harf;script=bng2;color=0000FF;",
   "NotoSansMyanmar:mode=harf;script=bng2;color=0000FF;",
   "NotoSansBamum:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
   "NotoSansDeseret:mode=harf;script=deseret;",
   "NotoSansMandaic-Regular:mode=harf;color=00FFFF;",
   "NotoSansOldSouthArabian:mode=harf;",
   "NotoSansOldNorthArabian:mode=harf;",
   "NotoSansImperialAramaic:mode=harf;",
   "NotoSansPalmyrene:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansHatran:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
   "NotoSansOldItalic:mode=harf;color=00FFFF;",
   "NotoSansRunic:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSansGothic:mode=harf;color=\mycolor;",
   "NotoSerifYezidi:mode=harf;color=00FF00;",
   "NotoSansYi:mode=harf;color=100000;",
   "Arial Unicode MS:mode=harf;",
   "DejaVuSans:mode=harf;script=grek;color=100000;",
   "cmuserif:mode=node;script=cyrl;color=101010;",
   "LastResort:mode=node;color=100010;",
 })}

\setmainfont{FreeSerif}[%
   Ligatures         = {Common,NoRare},%
   SmallCapsFeatures = {RawFeature=+c2sc},%
   Renderer          = Node,%
   Numbers           = Lining,%
   RawFeature={fallback=myfallback},
]


\newfontfamily\lastresort{LastResort}

\begin{document}


২০১৬ সাল থেকে এ পর্যন্ত সংস্থাটি ১৭টি উন্নয়নশীল দেশের ওপর মূল্যায়ন উপস্থাপন করেছে।\par


伯帛勃脖舶博渤霸壩灞

{\lastresort

ᠣᡳ  ᡳᠣᡳ᠊    ᠊ᡳᠣᡳ᠊   ᠊ᡳᠣᡳ

}

Anatolian 

\Uchar"14640

\directlua{for i=0x4E00, 0x6FFF do
tex.print(utf.char(i),", ")
end
}

\timerstop{document}

\directlua{tex.print("some test", timer.statistics("document"))}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another demonstration.

In a fair comparison, I only see a difference of 5x between lualatex and pdflatex.

I could have sworn that I saw lualatex taking 10x longer than pdflatex in one of my documents.  But, when I removed the use of `addfontfeature` from the lualatex version of my document (which uses fontspec and a different font), the performance discrepancy was not as large.

My document is much too large to post, but the python script below will generate a large `big.tex` file that is in some ways similar.  On my 2014 Macbook Air, I see the following compilation times for the 1150-page document:

- pdflatex: 5.530s
- lualatex: 29.158s

That's a factor of just over 5 (I ran three trials, all were in the 5.2-5.3x range.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

preamble8 = r"""\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myvn[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar A%
  {\textsuperscript{\itshape #1}\kern -.15em}%
  {\textsuperscript{\itshape #1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
"""

phrases = ["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ",
           "A lazy dog doesn't care. "
           ]

with open("big.tex", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(preamble8)
    for i in range(1, 100000):
        fp.write("\myvn{%d}" % (i % 42,))
        fp.write(phrases[i % len(phrases)])
        if i % 15 == 0:
            fp.write("\n\n")
        else:
            fp.write("\n")
    fp.write("\end{document}\n")
```