How can I start a LuaTeX-non-hb engine?
Writing and compiling documents, I noticed that sometimes "LuaTeX-1.18.0" is producer of the document, and in other cases it is "luahbtex-1.18.0". But I fail to find the switch, which command leads to which engine. The producer is displayed in the PDF info, I get it with Ctrl + D in a PDF viewer. TeX output says:

This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)

But we had LuaTeX (in my case: LuaLaTeX) long before HarfBuzz became a shaper. I guess "hb" is an abbreviation for "HarfBuzz"?
Can I make luatex use a non-hb engine? I found the man page luahbtex.man1.pdf on my system, saying:

The luahbtex variant can use the HarfBuzz engine for glyph shaping, instead of LuaTEX’s built-in shaper.

So: What other variants exist nowadays (TeX Live 2024)? How can I use them and is there a documentation? I'm just curious.

@rallg that's a very misleading description (and the symlink setup is common to all platforms that have usable symlinks, so macos, linux, cygwin, not windows) but if you change lualatex to symlink to luatex you'd have to rebuild the format

You can build LaTeX using LuaTeX instead of LuaHBTeX, e.g. on a Unix-like system
luatex -ini $(kpsewhich luatex.ini)

This will generate a format file lualatex.fmt, which you can then use as
luatex "&lualatex" <input-name>

and will get a log starting something like
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>

The reason that LuaHBTeX (LuaTeX + HarfBuzz) is used to build the standard LuaLaTeX format is that HarfBuzz is then available; that's not the same as enabled by default. If you run (stock) LuaLaTeX without any packages, you'll still be using the luaotfload shaper: the normal way to switch to HarfBuzz is using the appropriate fontspec setting.

There is also currently luajittex, which uses the 'just in time' version of Lua. However, the support for this version seems likely to end. As such, I do not think it's worth considering further.

Thank you! I understand that luahbtex simply says, HarfBuzz is available and I can use renderer = HarfBuzz or OpenType or AAT... So I need to find out what the differences are between the different shapers. One is described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635673/4736

There are two similar TeX engines: luatex (you can run it by luatex command) and luahbtex (you can run it by luahbtex command). The second one is linked with HarfBuzz library (as you mentioned in your question).
The LaTeX format uses luahbtex engine. It means that the fmt file is generated by luahbtex and the command lualatex runs luahbtex engine with LaTeX format. If you want to use pure luatex with LaTeX format, you have to generate the LaTeX format with luatex engine (it is not prepared in TeXlive distribution automatically) by luatex -ini lualatex.ini and then you can run luatex -fmt lualatex.
On the other hand, OpTeX uses luatex engine by default, so the command optex runs luatex engine with OpTeX format. If you want to use luahbtex engine with OpTeX, you have to generate OpTeX format by luahbtex -ini optex.ini and then run it by luahbtex -fmt optex.

Is there any advantage in building OpTeX with LuaTeX instead of LuaHBTeX?

@UdiFogiel I don't think so. The log output without using renderer = OpenType shows "renderer = basic", so as far as I understand, having luahbtex simply offers the possibility to use other shapers. I've got to find out, though, what the differences are.
