How to use two different bold variants of a variable openfont with fontspec in beamer?
I want to use Work Sans in a beamer. My institution requests us to use Work Sans Regular for main text, Work Sans Medium for headlines, and Work Sans Semibold for bolded text. I want to use the variable weight open type definitions so I don't need to carry multiple font files around. I have installed the open font types on my system (windows) and they show up in e.g. MS Word as selectable fonts (all the nine named weight variants show up as separate fonts, including Regular, Medium and Semibold).
The below attempt is in lualatex with fontspec.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[ BoldFont = Work Sans Semibold ]{Work Sans}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title Goes here}
Hello. Some \textbf{bold} text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Selected parts of the compilation trasncript are:
! Package fontspec Error: The font "WorkSansSemibold" cannot be found.

! Font \TU/WorkSans(0)/b/n/10.95=WorkSansSemibold:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig; at 10.95pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.

The resulting pdf has Work Sans Regular embedded in the file. No semibold variant.
Btw regular has weight 400, medium is 500, and semibold has 600, so I guess I could select them by variable instead of name, but I don't know how to do that either. When trying
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[ BoldFeatures = {Weight=600} ]{Work Sans}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title Goes here}
Hello. Some \textbf{bold} text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}

I get the errors
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/WorkSans(0)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/WorkSans(0)/m/n' instead on input line 8.

and
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Even if I did manage to load the Semibold as a bfseries, I don't know how a different boldface in frametitle.
Suggestions?

As a quick hack, maybe something like this could do the job:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Work Sans}[
    BoldFont            =   *,
    BoldFeatures        =   {Weight=900},
]
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+axis={wght=600}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title Goes here}
Hello. Some \textbf{bold} text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Updating from texlive 2020 to texlive 2024 made it compile perfectly on my local machine as well. thank you! Either it was a bug in previous versions of lualatex or in fontspec. upgrading resolvet it anyways.

@LudvigH Seems support for variable fonts was added in TL2021 or TL2022 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591485/36296
